# more than one stack per process?

Tags: multithreading, process, stack

I found this link:

[one quick question about stack of thread and process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283834/one-quick-question-about-stack-of-thread-and-process)

I understand why threads have separate stacks, but I read that the process may have two stacks . Why is this? could it be because we count the process stack + the thread stack?

Comment: Where did you read about a process having two stacks? A process have the same number of stacks as it has threads.

Comment: @joachim. Its mentioned in some tutorial material I got in one of my classes, but I didnt understand fully the reason, what was meant, so I asked here after seeing that other question.

Comment: @dexter Joachim is right: a process is just a container for threads, and threads have one stack. Or are you referring to a specific, particular case, OS, or architecture?

Comment: Some CPUs may run in one of two modes: User mode and supervisor mode. The supervisor mode is basically only for interrupts (software or hardware), and each mode have a separate stack. However it's still _per thread of execution_. To further complicate things, many old operating systems (and many modern embedded operating systems) don't have "threads" only processes. In these cases though, you can see each process as a single thread, which means there is still one (or two depending on CPU) stacks per thread.

Comment: The only possible explanation for a bizarre statement like that is that it actually meant *heap* instead of stack.  Heaps are owned by a process, not a thread.  And Windows programs indeed typically have at least two heaps.

Comment: @Hans passant. It didnt mean heap.

Comment: Maybe the source of confusion is that a stack is both the memory for local variables in languages like C but it is also a data structure, a LIFO container. Also, it is possible to not use a stack like in C but to allocate the working set for a function call dynamically and chain those together. Using setjmp/longjmp, you can also have multiple stacks used by the same thread. Dexter: Provide the actual text, at least some more of it, without that, it's impossible to tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is explained there:

- A process can have at least one thread, but it can have many more
- One thread has exactly one stack

So, if you say, that "One process can have two stacks" is partially true. The **process itself does not have** any stacks, but its **threads have** - as many as the number of threads.

Answer (score 2):

Modern operating systems allocate something called **kernel interrupt stack** for every user-level process. By user-level process, I mean any process that is not running in the **kernel-mode**. This makes it easier to switch to another process after a processor interrupt is handled. Suppose your processor is running **process x** that requires a system call to the kernel, and then a processor interrupt happened, which makes the processor run the handler for this interrupt. After this handler is done, the operating system can then choose to run process **y** instead of continuing process **x**. To support this type of switch, you need this kernel interrupt stack. In which we save **the whole execution environment for later use.** After process **y** is done, **x can continue doing its system call without any problems**. Note that if your user-level process doesn't have any system calls to the kernel-level, then you will have an **empty kernel interrupt stack**. This may be the second stack that you are talking about.
[Two Stacks Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvdNv.png)

This is used many times, not only to handle processor interrupts. Sometimes the process is ready and **waiting its turn to continue executing, then we have its state saved in its kernel interrupt stack, and when we start executing we fetch the state and put it in the registers**. Also, if the process requests an I/O operation to be done, this process is suspended till the I/O event is done, after that, it continues to execute with the same procedure explained above.

Due to memory limitations, **UNIX** started with few kernel interrupt stacks for all processes, not kernel interrupt stack for each process. However, after the memory became much cheaper, it's now easier to have kernel stack for each process.

For further information about it, you can review chapter 2 Kernel Abstraction and chapter 4 Concurrency and Threads in "Operating Systems: Principles and Practice 2nd Edition"